# cant understand usage of bitwise operations

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

a question from dec long contest (codechef), - http://www.codechef.com/problems/SANSKAR,
we simply have to tell whether n entities with with diff weights can be divided in given parts, with each part having same wt.
i failed to get AC, so looked at a solution - http://ideone.com/3hB8lI, 
this solution uses bitwise operations to simplify the problem, i know bitwise operations, but cant get the approach used in this solution,i know that copying odrs code is not a good idea but i want to know how the bitwise ops are used in the solution to get the answer..

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int T, N, K;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T--) {
        scanf("%d %d", &N, &K);
        long long a[N];
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            scanf("%lld", &a[i]);
        long long totSans=0;
        for(int i=0; i<N; i++)
            totSans+=a[i];
        long long eachSans;
        if(N<K || totSans%K) {
            printf("no\n");
            continue;
        }
        if(totSans%K==0)
            eachSans=totSans/K;
        long long takeAll=0;
        int cnt=0;
        for(int i=0; i<(1<<N); i++) {
            long long sum=0;
            for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
                if(i & (1<<j))
                    sum+=a[j];
            if(sum==eachSans && !(i & takeAll)) {
                takeAll |= i;
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        printf(!totSans || cnt>=K ? "yes\n" : "no\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to paste the entire code - only the relevant bits please. Also, [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Where is your indentation?

Comment: in the code martijnn2008

Comment: @faberlist _"in the code"_ There is **no proper** indentation in your code, no explanatory comments, no clear question asked.

Comment: BTW, the solution doesn't work : `1 1 2 4 5 5`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for(int i=0; i<(1<<N); i++)` is used to do the combination:
it loops from `0b00000` to `0b11111`

The following code:

```
long long sum=0;
for(int j=0; j<N; j++)
    if(i & (1<<j))
        sum+=a[j];
}
```

does the sum according to the previous 'mask':
so with `i == 0b1010`, sum will be `a[1] + a[3]` (mask index starts from right).